# Woocommerce Show only one price for variable product on discount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

Here is my WooCommerce website: sweetworldcandy.com

The issue is, in variable product price the least and the max 
value is showing what I want is if the product is not on sale show the least value if it is on sale show the least value and the least value of offer price by adding a slash as delete tag

I shared this three images below for reference:

[image] [image: if not on sale][image]

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: i looked all in the theme i coudnet find for that specific hook on woocommerce

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**2020 Update** *(for Woocommerce 3+)*

Replaced deprecated function `woocommerce_price()` by `wc_price()` since Woocommerce 3+:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'shop_variable_product_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html','shop_variable_product_price', 10, 2 );
function shop_variable_product_price( $price, $product ){
    $variation_min_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_min_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price('min', true);
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && !empty($variation_min_sale_price)){
        if ( !empty($variation_min_sale_price) )
            $price = '<del class="strike">' .  wc_price($variation_min_reg_price) . '</del>
        <ins class="highlight">' .  wc_price($variation_min_sale_price) . '</ins>';
    } else {
        if(!empty($variation_min_reg_price))
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.wc_price( $variation_min_reg_price ).'</ins>';
        else
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.wc_price( $product->regular_price ).'</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

---

Original thread *(before WooCommerce 3)*: The code below should do what you expect:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html', 'shop_variable_product_price', 10, 2);
add_filter('woocommerce_variable_price_html','shop_variable_product_price', 10, 2 );
function shop_variable_product_price( $price, $product ){
    $variation_min_reg_price = $product->get_variation_regular_price('min', true);
    $variation_min_sale_price = $product->get_variation_sale_price('min', true);
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() && !empty($variation_min_sale_price)){
        if ( !empty($variation_min_sale_price) )
            $price = '<del class="strike">' .  woocommerce_price($variation_min_reg_price) . '</del>
        <ins class="highlight">' .  woocommerce_price($variation_min_sale_price) . '</ins>';
    } else {
        if(!empty($variation_min_reg_price))
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $variation_min_reg_price ).'</ins>';
        else
            $price = '<ins class="highlight">'.woocommerce_price( $product->regular_price ).'</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

*The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works.

Comment: woocommerce_variable_sale_price_html is never called in my case, any suggestion why?

Comment: Doesn't work when variations have different prices (showing still the same price).