# how to change the price section in woocommerce product page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I've used woodmart theme for my website. These are all variable products. It is showing price like range value. but the price in A section must be printed like in b section. what I've to change here to do so.
[image: here is the sample output]

I need output like this, these were also variable products

[image: here is the image of the desired output]

While changing the weight by clicking the box the price needs to be updated dynamically ideally the selected weight's respective price have to be displayed instead of a range of prices

waiting for a response...

Comment: please refer to this link [Get the minimum variation price in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43279746/woocommerce-show-only-one-price-for-variable-product-on-discount)

Comment: The `Bumper Plates` is the variable product that's why it's showing the price range like min-max price kindly update or add more input to the question for better understanding.

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan question updated. please kindly review it and help me to solve the issue

Comment: @cbra The woodmart theme is a paid one and I've not used that theme therefore please wait some woodmart expertise will help you

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan :(

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to hide the price range for that particular product, you can use this CSS snippet. Replace 1234 with your actual product ID.

```
    .postid-1234 p.price {
       display:none;
       }
```

To disable the price range for all variable products, add this snippet to your child theme's function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'jean_variation_price', 9999, 2 );
  
function jean_variation_price( $price, $product ) {
   return ;
}
```

Comment: need to change for all product

Comment: For all products, please try the PHP snippet above.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with this theme.
It appears Woodmart hasn't supported this functionality.
You need to contact the theme author or try other ways to implement it by yourself.